# itoa in a template function

Tags: c++, templates, itoa

Code goes first:

```
template <typename T>
void do_sth(int count)
{
    char str_count[10];
    //...
    itoa(count, str_count, 10);
    //...
}
```

but I got some compile-error like this:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘itoa’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘itoa’ must be available
error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope
```

But I indeed included `<cstdlib>`.
Who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Have you #included <stdlib.h>? Or, better, <cstdlib> and use this function as std::itoa.

Comment: are you trying to do printf, operator << (ostream &, int), boost karma, boost format, lexical_cast etc etc. all over again?

Comment: @dimitri, I tried both ways, none works. I use stringstream instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that itoa is a non-standard function and not available on all platforms. Use snprintf instead (or type-safe std::stringstream).

Answer (score 2):

It is a non-standard function, usually defined in `stdlib.h` (but it is not gauranteed by ANSI-C, see the note below).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

then use `itoa()`

Note that `cstdlib` doesn't have this function.  So including `cstdlib` wouldn't help.

Also note that [this online doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) says,

> ## Portability
>
> This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of
>   C++, but is supported by some compilers.

If it's defined in the header, then in C++, if you've to use it as:

```
extern "C" 
{
    //avoid name-mangling!
    char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
}

//then use it
char *output = itoa(/*...params*...*/);
```

---

## A portable solution

You can use `sprintf` to convert the integer into string as:

```
sprintf(str,"%d",value);// converts to decimal base.
sprintf(str,"%x",value);// converts to hexadecimal base.
sprintf(str,"%o",value);// converts to octal base.
```

Comment: @Alcott: Actually, you don't have to use `std::`. I habitually wrote that :P

Comment: well, so I have to include stdlib.h not cstdlib, right? I thought cstdlib is an equivalent of stdlib.h in C++.

Comment: But it seems I still cannot pass the compilation.

Comment: @Alcott: that means, you don't have this header. As I said in my answer, it is not gauranteed that you will find it.

Comment: But if I don't use itoa in a template, I can just use it fine.

Comment: @Alcott: In that case, I'm sure you're doing something wrong. Post the code!

Comment: @Alcott: I've updated my answer with `extern "C"` declaration to avoid name-mangling. Try doing that. I also posted a portable solution!

Comment: My code is almost what I posted, I commented everything unrelevant.

Comment: @Alcott: You said, it's working if it's not template. So post a code which can reproduce the error.